# Compile Error.While i connect the project with the mongodb server and then it appeared

Tags: node.js

Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Module build failed: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/rules/no-unused-expressions' is not defined by "exports" in /home/imran/Documents/VS Code/Design Your Dress/design/frontend/node_modules/eslint/package.json
Referenced from:

I can't open it in the brower also.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.